# how do i change the color one by one to the items there with each click so that the previous one turns green again?

Tags: javascript

```
<button>Click!</button>
<ul>
    <li class="green">Home</li>
    <li class="green">faq</li>
    <li class="green">dropdown</li>
    <li class="green">about</li>
    <li class="green">contact</li>
</ul>
```

```
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

let btn = document.querySelector('button');

for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    let number = 0;

    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        li[number++].classList.add('red')
        if(number === li.length) {
            number = 0
        }
    })
}
```

I wanted a single item to turn red with each click and the previous one to turn green again

Comment: You are reinventing radio buttons

Comment: OP it looks like a nav bar. Why do you want to click a button to change the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this if this helps you. As soon as you press the button. Remove the red class from every element first and then add it like you were doing

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

let btn = document.querySelector('button');

for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    let number = 0;
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      for(let i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
        li[i].classList.remove('red')
      }
      li[number++].classList.add('red')
      if(number === li.length) {
         number = 0
      }
    })
}
```

```css
.green {
   color:green;
}

.red {
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Click!</button>
        <ul>
            <li class="green">Home</li>
            <li class="green">faq</li>
            <li class="green">dropdown</li>
            <li class="green">about</li>
            <li class="green">contact</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with JavaScript and one event listener

```js
document.querySelector(".menu").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  // find the li that was clicked
  const clickedLi = e.target.closest("li");
  if (!clickedLi) return;
  
  // see if we had something clicked already
  const selected = e.currentTarget.querySelector(".red");
  if (selected) selected.classList.remove('red');
  
  // update the class on what was clicked
  clickedLi.classList.add('red');
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

li.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="green">Home</li>
  <li class="green">faq</li>
  <li class="green">dropdown</li>
  <li class="green">about</li>
  <li class="green">contact</li>
</ul>
```

Using just html and css to make the selections

```css
.menu input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.menu input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><input type="radio" name="list" id="li1"><label for="li1">Foo</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="list" id="li2"><label for="li2">Bar</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="list" id="li3"><label for="li3">Baz</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="list" id="li4"><label for="li4">Cheese</label></li>
</ul>
```